# trying to convert textarea to hexadecimal in nodejs

Tags: node.js, hex, data-conversion

About a week ago I found a really nice converter from text to hexadecimal.

However, I didn't test text with newlines. Suddenly my nodejs app returned this:
fÚf

instead of:

f

f

the hexadecimal, according to [string-functions.com](http://string-functions.com/string-hex.aspx) should be 660d0a0d0a66 but my application returns 66da66

here is my "toHex" and "toText" code. This kind of converting isn't my strongest point.

```
var toHex = function toHex (str) {
  var hex = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    hex += '' + str.charCodeAt(i).toString(16)
  }
  return hex
}

var toText = function (hexx) {
  var hex = hexx.toString() // force conversion
  var str = ''
  for (var i = 0; i < hex.length; i += 2) {
   str += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(i, 2), 16))
  }
return str
}
```

edit:
when I insert 660d0a0d0a66 directly into my converter it convert to: f f, so there is a problem there as well....

Comment: I'm a little confused here... why don't you just do a simple `parseInt(str).toString(16)` instead of writing the whole toHex function?

Comment: because when I try to use parseInt(str).toString(16) it returns NaN (not a number)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your question is tagged nodejs so I guess you can use the native [Buffer](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html) object:
`new Buffer(hexString, 'hex')` -> gives you a buffer object of a hexadecimal string.
`new Buffer(string, 'utf-8')` -> gives you a buffer object of a string.
`yourBuffer.toString('hex')` -> gives you an hexadecimal string
... and so on

Comment: thanks, after some trial and error I managed to get it working. Although I'm running into other problems now.

But this solved the conversion problem :)